# ESXI Guest VM disk expand option grayed out

Tags: vmware, virtualization, esxi

I have ESXI 5.x Server. I am unable to expand the disk space in one of my VM guest. I have powered off it but still option is grayed out as showed in the image below ...
[esxi disk not expanding grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh4r2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YSK is correct. Increasing the size of a VMDK while as an IDE disk is not supported.

However, there are workarounds for that issue.

One example: http://www.yellow-bricks.com/2012/11/07/resizing-an-ide-virtual-disk-part-two/

1. Remove the IDE vmdk from the VM
2. Edit the “vmdk” file (can be found under cd
   /vmfs/volumes///)
3. Change ddb.adapterType from “ide” to “lsilogic”
4. Add the IDE vmdk to the VM
5. Change the size of the disk
6. Remove the IDE vmdk from the VM
7. Edit the “vmdk” file (can be found under cd
   /vmfs/volumes///)
8. Change ddb.adapterType from “lsilogic” to “ide”
9. Add the IDE vmdk to the VM
10. Power on the VM and “extend” the partition within the guest OS

Answer (score 0):

You're using an IDE disk.

As per [VMware KB 1004047](https://kb.vmware.com/kb/1004047):

`Note: Increasing the size of an IDE virtual disk using the vSphere Client is not supported. SCSI virtual disks are the only supported disk that can be expanded via the vSphere Client.`

Switch to a SCSI disk.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
Thank you all for your support replies. After doing some googling, I managed to sort it using single command line. I loggedin to esxi server (5.0) by SSH, and issued following command to increase the size of vmdk file.

```
vmkfstools -X 200G TMG.VMDK
```

& within 2 minutes, the vmdk file size increased from 50 GB to 250GB. After few minutes the size populated / refresh in esxi client as well. afterwards I use mini-tool partition tool to adjust the C: & D: partition size & all went perfect.